# Continuous to discrete legend on ggplot2 R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to plot curves with ggplot2 and group them by maturities. In my dataset maturities are expressed in remaining time in years.
My problem is that in my whole dataset I only have two maturities (0.15 and 0.2) but the legend displays color for 0.15, 0.16, 0.17...
Here is a screenshot :

[image]
Here is my code :

```
    call_vol_plot = ggplot(data=df[df$type=="C",],
       aes(x=strike,
           y=impliedVol,
           group = time_to_expiry,
           colour = time_to_expiry)) + geom_line() + geom_point(size=4, shape=21, fill="white")

    call_vol_plot = call_vol_plot + labs(title="Call Implied Volatility",
                           subtitle="Options on future contracts",
                           y="Implied Volatility",
                           x="Strike") + guides(color=guide_legend("Maturity in year"))
```

I tried scale_color_discrete but it didn't work. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution*** : Replacing `time_to_expiry` by `as.character(time_to_expiry)` work as expected. R can't make continuous values with variables of type characters. 
Many thanks to @Highland that almost gave the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Within aes, convert the `time_to_expiry` to factor `as.factor(time_to_expiry)`

and

```
+ scale_color_manual(values = c(0.15, 0.2))
```

Comment: It worked fine but there is neither any color nor any line now

Comment: @AlexM From the tidyverse page: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html looks maybe you can do something like `values = c(0.15 = 'red', 0.2 = 'blue'`

Comment: @Highland The problem with that solution is that you fix the possible maturities. If some additional maturities appears in the dataset, the solution won't work anymore. The solution I put in comment worked fine and for all dataset!
Thanks a lot!